# Creating a Canonical Question for Bulk Emailing

Tags: discussion

There are a *lot* of questions about bulk emailing.   I was trying to find one to close [Linux Mail Server Architecture for bulk mailing](https://serverfault.com/questions/515377/linux-mail-server-architecture-for-bulk-mailing) as, but didn't find anything.. specifically canonical..

Here's an idea.

**Q:**
My $employer wants to be able to send massive amounts of email, what's the best way to achieve this.
**A:**
Don't.

**A:**
Discussion of hosted SMTP services, hosted mailing list processors (without making recommendations).

**A:** Discussion of how to keep server reputation high, DKIM, SPF, unsubscribe, CAN-SPAM.

Comment: Stop spamming, please.

Comment: I am intrigued by your ideas and wish to subscribe to your newsletter.

Comment: Getting a lot of "my bulk emails are being blocked as spam by <insert provider here>" as well.  Fits with your "server rep" part.

Comment: The "A: Don't send spam, you'll mysteriously disappear from the internet" bit is important.

Comment: Another bulk email [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/525317/web-server-and-mail-server-on-same-machine) came in today. @Michael Hampton, any chance you could do a Bulk Email Canonical Q/A?

Answer (score 8):

I agree. I've also  noticed a significant uptick in "how do I sent a bajillion emails that my users have asked for using nothing but this VPS I have" style questions. The answer to that is usually:

> Er, you can't. Or, you could but you won't last long. Best to outsource it to a specialist; they have the infrastructure to cope with having an IP address get blacklisted as evil.

The existing canonicals don't seem to address this case very well at all. The most applicable is this one:

[How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam)

But that really doesn't go into enough of the right details for these newsletter/statusing questions we've been getting. [I did one recently where I tried to go into the details](https://serverfault.com/a/514911/3038), but didn't go into enough details for a great canonical.

Answer (score 7):

I do run a service which sends bulk email, in irregular volumes, which occasionally gets me classified by Sender Score as a "High Volume Sender". (Though not today...) And yes, I run it on a little 512MB VPS.

So I know a few things about this.

[image: The blue porcupine's Sender Score]

When I get back from my vacation I'll see about writing a canonical answer about bulk mailing.

Comment: I would be fascinated to see how you're doing it